# How to list the content of a VM's directories from the host?

Tags: python, virtualbox, host

I instakked VirtualBox on Windows 7. I chosed the option "Host Only Network", so I can access, for example, Apache server installed on my VM.
In short, this is my setup:

```
- Host: Windows 7
- Guest: Windows 7
- Networking: NAT+ Host Only Networking
```

My question is: is there anyway in Python programming language to access the logical hard drive on my VM where an other Windows 7 is installed ? I would love to be able to access and list contents of the directories of my VM (windows 7) from my host (windows 7) You can just give me a hint to a given library or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [enable Telnet on the guest OS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732046%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and then access it from the host using the [telnetlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html) module.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you think there is something similar for SSH (sor security reasons) ?

Comment: `Telnet` is the closest thing you'll find to SSH in Windows, albeit you could install an SSH server on the Guest OS using a third party software like `freeSSHd` or `Bitvise SSH`.